# how to make a search bar responsive using jquery or css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function searchToggle(obj, evt) {
  var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
  if (!container.hasClass('active')) {
    container.addClass('active');
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else if (container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0) {
    container.removeClass('active');
    // clear input
    container.find('.search-input').val('');
  }
}
```

```css
.search-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 79%;
  top: -25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 70px 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  transform: translate(0, 60px);
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before,
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
  width: 4px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  top: 18px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
  right: -50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before,
.search-wrapper .close::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
  width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>
```

After a lot of research, changes I finally managed to make and position my search bar. But according to me it is not performing the **search function**. *for example, if I type anything in it like 'home' and press the search icon nothing happens*. So I want to ask whether I am wrong i.e. the search function is working and secondly I want to make it **responsive** like Google's search bar. I mean I want it to remember searches and also shorten the results as I type.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It only uses CSS and is leightweight. You can find it well documented at [Bootstrap Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp). If you don't want to use a Framework you can try building something for yourself. For that purpose you can simply look again at bootstrap (or another CSS Framework) and copy whatever you want to use.

Again, you should use a CSS Framework for responsive designs, they help alot and make your life easier.

Regards, Megajin